# How do I configure Hardware RAID when installing Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid, raid-1

I have a DELL precision workstation which is supposed to have a Hardware RAID controller. However, I have no knowledge/experience with setting up that kind of system. It is currently running Ubuntu 14.04, and `lspci -vv| grep 'RAID'` gave me this info:

```
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset SATA RAID Controller
```

- This means I actually have a hardware RAID right?

I currently have an SSD-disk as my system partition and two 2TB Harddisks as `/home` partition, which should be configured to mirror each other as RAID 1 (not sure how to check that, though).

I now want to replace both 2TB "/home"-harddisks of my system with bigger (4Tb) versions, and at the same time do a complete new installation of the most recent Xubuntu LTS. However, I still want the new Harddisks to mirror each other with RAID 1.

- How do I configure the Hardware RAID during Installation of Xubuntu for the new hard-disks?
- Are there special considerations when choosing new hard disks (is it possible that some might not be compatible with the RAID controller)?
- Do I have to partition the new disks in any special way (otherwise I would just create a single ext4 partition on each of them)?

Thanks for any help...

Comment: I'm not sure about that controller but most Intel controllers are software raids. If it is an actual hardware raid controller (assuming you configured it - usually you will have a prompt sometime during boot) your system won't see the disks but just one "virtual" disk that represents the raid. As such during installation you would already need to have a kernel that has the necessary drivers or load a corresponding module.

Comment: I can't remember any such prompt during boot. I remember being somewhat worried if the raid was being correctly configured when I set up the system quite some time ago (was originally delivered with windows, which I replaced with Ubuntu). When the IT-guy (who, alas, was not available when I set up the system, and now I'm at a new position without IT-department) last checked it, he said RAID seemed to be running and working. In that case, would it be safe to assume that the necessary drivers (for this controller at least) might already be included in the standard Ubuntu distributions?.

Comment: Depending on what your setup looks like it might also be just running in a JBOD configuration. You probably should check the manual of your motherboard.

Comment: running `lsblk` gives me the two harddrives as "sdb" and "sdc". Both have a block of type "dmraid" which contains a single partition mounted as "/home". Is that a hint towards an actual RAID? (not sure where to find my motherboards manual, can't find it in on the "Documentation" disks delivered with the workstation)

Comment: @jov14 it appears your installation is recognizing the software raid devices, but their should be a singular device available to the OS that is the single RAID device.  Use "fdisk -l"  For example, when I use MDADM, if I run "fdsik -l", I get the raw drives listed AND the MD raid devices listed separately.  The MDx device is the device I format and use and I ignore the underlying devices.   You should have something similar for your dmraid device(s).

Comment: @jov14 configuration of your software RAID devices is probably done in the BIOS;Hardware and FakeRAID devices are typically made before  loading of the boot loader on the boot drive meaning you enter configuration mode somehow before booting the OS.  For integrated RAID, this would be in the BIOS, but sometimes it is a separate configuration utility outside of the BIOS.